# CSS how to select element with specific class inside div with same the class except the first one

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get an h2 element with a specific class name inside divs with the same class name except the first one. here is the structure:

```
<div class="rank-content">
   <h2 class="rank-badge">test</h2>
</div>
<div class="rank-content">
   <h2 class="rank-badge">test</h2>
</div>
<div class="rank-content">
   <h2 class="rank-badge">test</h2>
</div>
```

I am trying to change css appearance of all rank badge except from the the first .ranked-content.
I've tried this one but it changes all rank-badge h2:

```
.ranking-content:not(:first-child) .rank-badge {

}
.ranking-content:not(:nth-child(1)) .rank-badge {

}
```

any ideas? thanks in advance.

Comment: `rank-content` ≠ `ranking-content`

Comment: oh sorry, I've typed the wrong class. this is supposed to be .ranking-content.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `.ranking-content` and that isn't the name of the class you have in your HTML.

The name in the class attribute is `rank-content`.

This is how you should call it in your CSS.

```
.rank-content:not(:first-child) .rank-badge {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to create a unique class variant for your first `rank-badge`
class such as `rank-badge 2` ?

Comment: Yes, i've tried this one and it works, but I want to know why the above mentioned code isn't working. also, I am implementing php code here, so if I create rank-badge-2 for example, it will adjust my code for backend making more lines of code. I want it to automatically detect in css keeping php as short as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this.

```
.rank-content:not(:first-of-type) .rank-badge {
 
}
```